# How to cd & mkdir at the same time in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is it possible to do something like below in Windows Command Prompt:

```
cd C:\MyFiles mkdir Files
```

What I'm trying to do is go into a specific folder using the `cd` command and then create a new folder using the `mkdir` command. I need to do this in one single command/line. This could be done by two separate commands, but I don't have this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd /D C:\MyFiles & mkdir Files
```

Here's the [documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).

The `/D` parameter will also change the drive.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds. +1 :)

Comment: `cd /D C:\MyFiles & mkdir Files`

Comment: I definitely agree with @Vlastimil's modification. Leaving off the `/D` flag has bit me in the past.